# How to stack ols results as a table in dolphindb?

Tags: regression, dolphindb

I need to run a regression with group by in dolphindb. Each group's regression result is a vector and I would like to stack all results as a table, with each coefficient estimate as a column.

```
t=table(1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 as id, rand(1.0, 15) as y, 1..15 as x1, 3 2 9 5 0 6 7 8 9 10 3 5 0 8 0 as x2)
select ols(y, (x1, x2)) from t group by id
```

I got the following error message:

```
select ols(y, x1, x2) as ols_y from t group by id => The column 'ols(y, x1, x2)' must use aggregate function.
```

Does anyone know a better way to stack the results than to use to a -for loop?

Answer (score 0):

As the result of ols is a vector for each group, you can specify the result as a composite column in dolphindb in the following way:

```
t=table(1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 as id, rand(1.0, 15) as y, 1..15 as x1, 3 2 9 5 0 6 7 8 9 10 3 5 0 8 0 as x2)
select ols(y, (x1, x2)) as `intercept`x1`x2 from t group by id
```